# print echo json_encode values in php from modal dialog

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function book_update()
{
    $data = array(
        'book_isbn' => $this->input->post('book_isbn'),
        'book_title' => $this->input->post('book_title'),
        'book_author' => $this->input->post('book_author'),
        'book_category' => $this->input->post('book_category'),
    );
    $this->book_model->book_update(array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

i want two parameter based on this output thats why

Comment: what type of parameter u want?

Answer (score 1):

**In Model**

```
public function book_update(....)
{
    $data = array(
        ...
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    if (!$this->db->update('mytable', $data))
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

**In Controller**

```
$result = $this->book_model->book_update(array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')), $data);
echo json_encode(array("status" => $result));
```

**In Html**

You will get TRUE of FALSE based on update success/fail.

Comment: i want integer value ex : $markid = $this->input->post('book_isbn');

Comment: where is this comes `$markid = $this->input->post('book_isbn');`??